# Load a File in a JSF application

Tags: java, file, loading

My logic need to load a File that is embedded in the applications .war.
The file is located at the root of the application. It works fine on my machine
because the path is hard coded: File hmmFile = new File("/home/kirill/projetos/biosearchrefinement/pos-en-bio-medpost.HiddenMarkovModel");
but when I deploy it to a server it won`t work because the absolute path is different.

I tried to use ClassLoader but got a null reference and tried to use FacesContext but no success either. I am using glassfish 3 and Mojarra 2.1.6

My project tree looks like this:
[image: Project tree]

In my code I am referencing the file like this:

```
File hmmFile = new File("/home/kirill/projetos/biosearchrefinement/pos-en-bio-medpost.HiddenMarkovModel");
```

But this only works when I run the application locally, if I deploy it to a remote server obviously it will stop loading that File. I would like to load this file Relatively to the project`s root folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your vague description, what you need is to use the `Class.getResourceAsStream()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using getRealPath() from ExternalContext.

```
ExternalContext ext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
String resourcesPath = ext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/resources");
File hmmFile = new File(resourcesPath + "/pos-en-bio-medpost.HiddenMarkovModel");
```

Worked fine!